# Universal set for linearly ordered sets of given cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

It is easy to see that every infinitely countable linearly ordered set embeds into Q (rational numbers) with its linear order.("Linear order"="total order". All embeddings are assumed to preserve linear orders). In fact, we expect that Q is a "minimal" linearly ordered set with this property.

What about sets of higher cardinalities? Specifically, is it true that for any cardinality X, there is a linearly ordered set S, which is "minimal" with respect to the property that every linearly ordered set of cardinality X embeds into S?

What is S for X=continuum?

Comment: Of course there is, since $\mathcal P(X)$ embeds every partial order on $X$, so just extend the inclusion to be a linear order and you can create a universal linear order. So there is a universal order which has minimal cardinality (which might be or might not be the order we created above). I suspect that your actual question is what can we say on the minimal cardinality of a universal linear order for orders of size continuum, and here I believe the answer is fairly independent of $\sf ZFC$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry, I dont understand your comment starting with "P(X) embeds every partial order on X". Btw, I am considering linear/total orders only.

Comment: Yes, but recall that every partial order can be extended into a linear order.

Comment: What do you mean when you say that Q is minimal? A natural requirement that one might impose is to ask if for every cardinal $\kappa$, there is a linear order of size $\kappa$ which embeds all other linear orders of cardinality $\kappa$. This is a question that has received some attention.